# Operating Systems - General Process Creation

Tags: process, operating-system

Review Question

> Consider the Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    putchar('X');
    exit(0); 
}
```

> Suppose it is compiled an an a.out file is generated. now suppose that a user in a local console window types a.out and hits the return key. what happens? be sure to describe a plausible but detailed and comprehensive sequence of operating system actions and events, not just what the user sees.

My answer

- First, the shell will create a process in User Space
- Then it will perform the system call 'putchar' Which simulates input, and the process will switch to kernel mode
- It will then add the process (thread) to the long term scheduler where it will join the set of all processes that are ready to run
- Once it is selected, it will move to the short term scheduler, where it will receive some processing time (ready -> running)
- Since this process is an IO bound process, it will then head to the IO queue, where it will be stored in a buffer where it awaits execution (running -> waiting)
- Once the IO is complete, the putchar call will print the X on the peripheral for which it is applied (the monitor) (waiting -> running)
- Once the process returns to the short term scheduler it will again receive more processing time. Since there is nothing left to do but terminate, the process terminates (running -> terminated)

Is this valid understanding? Am I missing some critical concepts for process creation? I know it is relatively simple process, but please advise anything I am missing.

Thanks for reading, and thanks in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the shell will create a process in User Space

// A lot of things happen before this!!

//The program will be loaded by the loaded.

//VM areas will be created for this process.

//Linking for library files will be done.

//Then a series of pagefault will occur will happen to bring your file on physical and  virtual memory

Then it will perform the system call 'putchar' Which simulates input, and the process will switch to kernel mode

//putchar in not at all a system call!!!!

//putchar will call its library implementation, which will further call a  write() system call  and your program will get trapped inside the kernel

It will then add the process (thread) to the long term scheduler where it will join the set of all processes that are ready to run

//Totally depends upon the scheduling algorithms.. might be possible your process will be first to run!!

Once it is selected, it will move to the short term scheduler, where it will receive some processing time (ready -> running)

//Right, waiting on RunQ

Since this process is an IO bound process, it will then head to the IO queue, where it will be stored in a buffer where it awaits execution (running -> waiting)

//Sort of, it will be waiting on I/O queue, waiting for an interrupt, to write on o/p device

Once the IO is complete, the putchar call will print the X on the peripheral for which it is applied (the monitor) (waiting -> running)
//Correct

Once the process returns to the short term scheduler it will again receive more processing time. Since there is nothing left to do but terminate, the process terminates (running -> terminated)

//Before this it will again get trapped inside the kernel when your program will execute RETURN statement.

//It will call the back the startup function which was responsible for calling the main() function.

//Then startup() function will return 0 to operating system, and hence OS will kill this process and moce it to terminated state..

I still don't think its a complete version as 100's of machine instruction  will be executed for this program and its difficult to pin point each and everyone..

But, still if you have some doubt post your comment!!]

Hope this will help!!!